# Google Apps Script: spreadsheets: How do I get number of sheets, set last one as active duplicate and rename?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to get the syntax correct...

I'm trying to get the total number of sheets in a spreadsheet and set the last one to the active sheet. I then want to duplicate the sheet, rename and delete rows 3 to the last row.

This is some of the code I've been playing with:

```
    var logbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("keycode here");
    var logbookSheets = logbook.getSheets();
    var numSheets = logbook.getNumSheets();
    logbook.setActiveSheet(logbookSheets[numSheets]).duplicateActiveSheet();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used `duplicateActiveSheet` and since the code editor does not complete for it (at least not yet), I'd not use it.

Here's is how I'd do it:

```js
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ss-key');
  var sheets = logbook.getSheets();
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheets[sheets.length-1]);
  sheets[sheets.length-1].copyTo(ss).setName('NewName');
```

Comment: Here's a little more info on how I was hoping to use the script:  I have created a Google Site page and have embedded a google apps script on that page with a UI that allows me to input info that then pushes the info to a spreadsheet in my google docs so I wouldn't have the spreadsheet open. The spreadsheet logs the info passed to it. I want to create a sheet for each year. It will start with 2012 and when I enter new data that has a year 2013 it should duplicate the 2012 sheet, rename 2013 and delete lines 4 on.

Comment: Here is a link to the duplicateActiveSheet:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#duplicateActiveSheet

Comment: I've actually since gotten the duplicate sheet to work. I'm now trying to extract the year out of the date I've input in order to compare, activate the duplicate sheet and to rename. I can't seem to figure out how to extract the date from the date field.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the duplicateActiveSheet, I did not knew of it (and also the script editor code completion). I think getting the year of a date object is just `date.getYear()`.

Comment: @sbaden : you can have a look at [this ref page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: You're welcome Henrique. So how would I use the date.getYear()?  This is the code I currently have:  var labelDate = app.createLabel("Date of Flight:");
  var textBoxDate = app.createDateBox().setName("date").setStyleAttribute("color", "#a7a7a7");  Would I use something like this: textBoxDate.date.getYear()?

Comment: Your doubt is not really related to dates or copying sheets anymore. It is: "How to get the value of a field in UiApp?" You need to add your widgets as callback elements of your handler, if you still have doubts about it, I strongly suggest you to start a new question, as this is not suitable for comments nor related to the original question.